# How to use other function in reformulate in r

Tags: r, model, formula, tidyverse

I am trying to use `reformulate()` in `gam()` and get a problem.

My model like this:

```
g <- mgcv::gam(mpg ~ s(hp) + am + qsec, data = mtcars)
```

Then I use `reformulate()` to rewrite the formula but get an error:

```
g2 <- mgcv::gam(reformulate(c(s('hp'),'am','qsec'), response = 'mpg'), data = mtcars)
```

I think the arguments in `reformulate()` can not use function(in my example I use `s()`), and then I delete `s()` and the code run :

```
g3 <- mgcv::gam(reformulate(c('hp','am','qsec'), response = 'mpg'), data = mtcars)
```

My question is how can I use functions in `reformulate()` or suggest some other alternatives.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases you can create a string object and convert it into formula.

```
reponse = 'mpg'
terms <- c('s(hp)',  'am',  'qsec')

g <- mgcv::gam(as.formula(sprintf('%s~%s', reponse, 
               paste(terms, collapse = '+'))), data = mtcars)
g

#Family: gaussian 
#Link function: identity 

#Formula:
#mpg ~ s(hp) + am + qsec

#Estimated degrees of freedom:
#2.36  total = 5.36 

#GCV score: 8.837538
```

where

```
paste(terms, collapse = '+') #returns
#[1] "s(hp)+am+qsec"
#and
sprintf('%s~%s', reponse, paste(terms, collapse = '+')) #returns
#[1] "mpg~s(hp)+am+qsec"
```